# Operating on sealed UiState classes in the Android ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I'm reading the [Crash Course on the Android UI layer](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/crash-course-on-the-android-ui-layer-part-1-2094221a9be3) and there it's proposed to model complex UI state via a sealed class e.g. like so:

[image]

I would expose such a state to the UI (Compose) in the form of

```kotlin
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<HomeUiState>(HomeUiState.NoPosts()) // flow of type HomeUiState
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

Now, if I trigger business logic from my UI e.g.

```kotlin
// in the UI
when (uiState) {
    is HasPosts -> { // smart cast from interface type to concrete data class HomeUiState.HasPosts
        // Action triggered e.g. by a button
        viewModel.refreshPosts()
    }
}
```

It seems I always have to do a type cast in the ViewModel before I can access the members which are specific to the UiState from which the function was triggered.

```kotlin
// ViewModel
fun refreshPosts() {
    if(uiState.value is HomeUiState.HasPosts) {
        // here I can access HasPosts's specfic members like postsFeed
        uiState.postsFeed.refresh()
    }
}
```

I can't imagine I have to do a type cast in every ViewModel function to get access to the properties of the UiState. E.g. think of UiStates like `UiState.Loading` and `UiState.Success`: the majority of functions in the ViewModel would operate on the `UiState.Success` state and just because I have another UiState I need to cast everywhere?

I'm certainly missing something here?!

Comment: What exactly is `PostsFeed`? If it's a Repository of some sorts, it doesn't make a lot of sense to make it part of the `HasPosts` UI state.

Comment: Not clearly visible from the article but I guess some kind of class to hold a list of posts and metadata? For the sake of the questions lets consider it to be a List of Posts that got fetched from a local database

Answer (score 0):

Only your `when` block in the observer knows that `uiState.value` is of a particular type. By the time you call `viewModel.refreshPosts()` the underlying value may have changed, so you would need to once again confirm the type.

Instead, assuming this is to change the state of some "refresh" button for example, use the observer block to update your click handling, and pass the strongly-typed value to your `ViewModel` method:

```
fun refreshPosts(feed: PostsFeed) {
  feed.refresh()
}
```

Then your observer can just pass in the smart-casted object directly:

```
when (uiState) {
  is HasPosts -> 
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener { 
      viewModel.refreshPosts(uiState.postsFeed)
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this is a simplified example, but in your case you probably don't need the `refreshPosts` method at all and should just directly invoke `uiState.postsFeed.refresh()`.